# "Objurgate" vs "Berate"

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, word-difference

Although googled these terms, I'm pretty confused between the two. Also, how do they differ in the following sentence?

> *"I prefer dad's **objurgation** to Mom's **berating** me over the condition of my room"*

Comment: I don't think they differ by much. Both are synonymous to **"Being scolded at"**.

Comment: This is the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=objurgation%2Cberating&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobjurgation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cberating%3B%2Cc0), showing the frequency of usage of '**Objurgation**' and '**Berating**'

Comment: Most native speakers go an entire lifetime and never hear or see the word **objurgate**.

Comment: Agreed with @TRomano.  I would avoid objurgate altogether.

Comment: @Varun KN: Absolutely! The relative rarity of ***objurgate*** is even more starkly illustrated by checking [the basic verb forms.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=objurgate%2Cberate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobjurgate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cberate%3B%2Cc0) From a learner's perspective I'd say the only sensible thing to do is forget you ever met the word (to the extent that native speakers ever encounter it, I'm sure that's mostly what they do! :)

Comment: I still remember when I first encountered the word 'objurgate'.  It was when I read this question.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, the difference is this:

**If you use the word *objurgate*, people are unlikely to understand.**

Most people don't use or know this word.  It has no attestations at all in the Corpus of Contemporary American English; in the 14-billion word iWeb corpus, *objurgate* appears only 5 times, making its frequency less than 1 per billion words.  That makes it less common than words like *spinous*, *quagga*, *krait*, *ramie*, *eschar*, or even *uxorilocal*.

When you're learning a language, it's important to prioritize vocabulary which people actually use and understand.  *Objurgate* does not qualify.

In contrast, *berate* is a relatively common word, and you can expect native speakers to understand you readily when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Though the two are similar and the minor differences could be subjective, to me, **objurgate** sounds more like plain *scolding* or *being shouted at*.

**berate** on the other hand has a meaning closer to *being discouraged* or *being criticized* for one's action. It is more closely associated with *hopelessness*.

Comment: I have never heard of the word objurgate. Can I ask in what context you have encountered this word, and why you think it sounds like "plain scolding or being shouted at"?

Comment: I found this interesting write-up of objurgate: https://wordfoolery.wordpress.com/tag/objurgatory/ It suggests that the root meaning would be to take someone for judgement before the law.  I would think that implies a more rigorous and less emotional judgement, but the word is so obscure it's hard to assign any implication to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a sentence you found in someone else's work, rather than one you formulated yourself. Both words mean essentially the same thing (to scold or rebuke), though other answers are correct that objurgate is *extremely* obscure and possibly a case of [thesaurusitis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MA70DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT6&pg=PT184#v=onepage&q&f=false). What the author is likely doing here is not providing a direct contrast between the two activities, but simply using two different words in order to avoid repetition. Consider this alternative version:

> I prefer dad's **scolding** to Mom's **scolding** me over the condition of my room

Native English speakers would find this sentence clunky because it uses the same word twice in close succession. The sentence simply means that he prefers the way his father scolds him to the way his mother did; the difference in word choice is just to give some variety, in part by using two different endings (-ing and -tion).